# Does any one know the all the possible metadata of the Compile msbuild element?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

For instance, I know of Link, DependentUpon and SubType. I am wondering if there are any more nifty metadata children of Compile. I use Link and DependentUpon a lot and really like them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the file `%FrameWorkDir%\MSBuild\Microsoft.Build.Commontypes.xsd`, where `%FrameWorkDir%` is the location of the .NET Framework in question (example: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`). From what I can see, the following are available:

- AutoGen
- CopyToOutputDirectory
- DependentUpon
- DesignTime
- DesignTimeSharedInput
- Include
- Link
- SubType
- Visible

As to what they are and what they can do, I'm unsure.